# Find the nth Node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Using this bootstrap:

```
template <class Comparable>
const Comparable& AugmentedBinarySearchTree<Comparable>::NthElement(int n)
{
  int *i = 0;
  return NthElement(root, i, n)->element;
}
```

How would you find the nth node in a BST using the `nodesVisited` pointer to keep track of the nodes checked?

```
template <class Comparable>
BinaryNode<Comparable>* AugmentedBinarySearchTree<Comparable>::
NthElement(BinaryNode<Comparable> *t, int *nodesVisited, int n) const
{

}
```

Each node in the BST has a pointer `left` and `right` and a value of `template <class Comparable>` called `element`.

Comment: What is meant by "Nth node" in a binary tree?  Doesn't that depend on how the binary tree is traversed?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie by finding the "Nth node" I mean the nth value that was inserted into the tree, pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Traverse the tree in whatever order you want (probably in-order). Increment `*nodesVisited` for each node. Stop when `*nodesVisited == n`.

Comment: @m_callens - It is not self-explanatory.  Get an illustration of a binary tree, heck, with just a root and a left / right node.  Which branch, left or right, was populated first?  Can you tell, even without writing a program, which data item came first?  Was it the item that was on the left, or was it the item that appeared on the right?  Also, you didn't state the order you used to insert, which is why I stated the issue of traversal.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me (from your comment) like you're looking for Boost's multi-index container (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). You would have vector and map views, and insert with push_back into the vector view while using the map view to search by key. Then you would use the vector view to get the nth-inserted element.